# Google Drive-Picker custom for mobile

Tags: slack

I see that google drive picker have a minimum size frame, it can't be responsive on mobile web view. But I saw an extension google drive on slack and it's responsive.

Anybody know how to build google drive picker like extension on slack? Is drive picker actually able to modify to make it responsive or is it customize by Google Drive API?

Any tutorial reference is apreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no specific tutorial with regard to mobile support of [Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) for mobile devices. I believe that the Slack team has written their own implementation for the interface and just makes calls to [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk). So if you like the same functionality, it is expected that you also write your own.

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918206/google-drive-picker-javascript-not-mobile-friendly-responsive) seems to confirm this also.